# Collision not properly working

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I am creating a game where the enemies move in 4 directions up,down,left,right. Currently when the enemies collide with the rocks in my game they just get stuck there. The enemies move based on what their "move" int variable is; 1 is move Right, 2 is move left, 3 is Down, and 4 is up. So depending on what their move variable is at the time of colliding they are supposed to move in the opposite direction until they are no longer colliding.

enemy moving code

```
public void enemyMove()
{
    movetime--;

    if (move == 1)
    {
        position.X += speed;
        if (position.X > 1320)
        {
            move = rand.Next(1, 5);
            position.X -= 5;
            enemyMove();
        }
    }

    if (move == 2)
    {
        position.X -= speed;
        if (position.X < 160)
        {
            move = rand.Next(1, 5);
            position.X += 5;
            enemyMove();
        }
    }

    if (move == 3)
    {
        position.Y += 5;
        if (position.Y > 780)
        {
            move = rand.Next(1, 5);
            position.Y -= 5;
            enemyMove();
        }
    }

    if (move == 4)
    {
        position.Y -= 5;
        if (position.Y < 120)
        {
            move = rand.Next(1, 5);
            position.Y += 5;
            enemyMove();
        }
    }
}
```

rock collision code (the e is the enemy class, which is where the enemyMove code is)

```
if (e.boundingBox.Intersects(r.boundingBox))
{
    switch (e.move)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            e.position.X -= e.speed;
            //e.move = 2;
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            e.position.X += e.speed;
            //e.move = 1;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            e.position.Y -= e.speed;
            //e.move = 4;
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            e.position.Y += e.speed;
            //e.move = 3;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I commented out the lines that when its colliding it changes its move variable because it should be fine with what i have so far, but the enemies keep getting stuck. When I did have the lines uncommented, the enemies would get free after like 6 seconds of "spazzing" out (cant think of a better way to describe it).

if there is any more code you need to see in order to help, please ask and I will get it for you

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean flag for when the `enemy` has collided and is attempting to correct - as this code stands, the `if(e.boundingBox.Intersects(r.boundingBox))` checks every frame, and thus will result in a series of infinite turn-arounds.

Also look into Ray-casting and a priori collision detection, as this can help with the spazzing issues and will prevent visual instances of enemies halfway embedded in walls for the couple of frames it takes to process a collision-and-correction.